# Changing textView height depending of text it contain

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have detail view controller that shows up after user click on cell, it contain UIImageView, textview that have some text. Sometimes it have several rows of text, sometimes a lot of text. What i want to, is change textView frame height dynamically, depending of amount of text it contain.

That is what i have tried:

```
-(void)configureTextView{

    CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.myTextView.contentSize.height;
    self.myTextView.frame = frame;
}
```

But it still show me textView that not fit whole rows of text (user can actually scroll it up and down, feature that i don't want to). How to change textView frame height for height, that actually fit whole text? And how to measure final height size of that textView?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `[self.myTextView sizeToFit];` and then see if it updates it for you.

Comment: No problem. If it worked, make sure you mark as Best Answer so others can see. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)heightForTextView:(UITextView*)textView containingString:(NSString*)string
```

{

```
float height = [self.model boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthOfTextView, 20000000)
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15]}
                                        context:nil].size.height + 16;




return height;
```

}